# convention of writing vector symbols

Tags: vectors

I am always confused when I am denoting vectors. From Wikipedia, it says the common convention of vectors are always in lowercase boldface letters or with arrow. However, our math teacher writes vector simply by lowercase letter (like u or v). For instance, $u=i+j+k$. Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: @Randall Do you mean there is no convention of vector notation?

Comment: There are common conventions for sure, but if you invent boldface chalk please let me know.

Comment: In the end, it's just symbols. Note that in physics, the mentioned convention is not used for members in arbitrary vector spaces, but only for vectors in physical 3D space, or sometimes in 4D spacetime. Vectors in the state space of quantum mechanics are commonly written like this: $\left|\psi\right\rangle$.

Comment: @UserAb  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can write them in various ways. For example you can write:

$$\vec{v} \quad \overline{v} \quad \underline{v} \quad \mathbf{v}$$

$$\vec{\mathbf{v}} \quad \overline{\mathbf{v}} \quad \underline{\mathbf{v}}$$

Personally I prefer $\overline{\mathbf{v}}$ and $\underline{\mathbf{v}}$ because are easier to write.

But in some cases you can simply write $v$, for example when you write about vectorial spaces.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to write boldface letters on paper/board, so a vector symbol above the letter is used, even with i, j, and k. Some teachers are lazy and omit the arrow, which they shouldn't because then one could confuse the letters as being components of a vector, so ask when in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

yes and it’s more simple to work in this way

usually to avoid misunderstanding one reserves some symbols to the vectors (e.g. v,w,u) and others for numbers (e.g a,b,c)